# (Language Agnostic) Design Pattern for Unreliable Data Partner

Tags: design-patterns

What is the (generic, any OO) design pattern for the use case where you have a client that puts/gets data from the server, but the server isn't always available?

Comment: If you question is just about availability, there are number of pattern/best practices for asynchronous messaging systems. You can try out: http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/asynchronous_queuing

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: I have added an answer with further options and existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is only about availability and the api/system can work with asynchronous communication, I recommend using messaging solutions.

I have personally used:

1. Custom platform based on [Apache Active MQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) . Highly scale-able infra piece. You can consider this if you require a solution across your organization or across several service
2. [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) This is implementation of Enterprise Integration Pattern. If your use case requires integration over numerous technologies and stacks , you can go with Camel.

Not used till now:

1. [JMS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncdq/index.html) Java messaging Queues
2. [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) Amazon AWS solution.
3. [Azure Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/service-bus/)

There are  a lot more custom libraries for specific stack/language and use cases. You can search for specific ones on google.
You can go through them and select what suits your usecase.